# How to build a graph in a div that is still being rendered?

Tags: highcharts, vue.js, plotly

In our webapps, we often show a graph or 3D render of data that comes back from an AJAX call.

Until the user clicked on a button, and the JSON is returned from the server, the div containing the graph or 3D model is not yet shown, for example by setting the div with a v-show attribute: `<div id="graph" v-show="data.show_graph"></div>`

The problem with this approach is that graph libraries, such as highcharts or plotly, require this div to be present to get the height and the width of the div to start building the graph. But even if we first set the v-show flag to true, it is not fast enough rendered so the graph javascript code can use the dimensions of the div.

Do you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Use a render function or JSX instead of a single file component.  I do something similar but built around ag-grid. [Render functions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am also using `Vue` with `Highcharts` and have ran into a similar problem. My solution was simply call [`reflow()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow) on the chart after the Div is showing.
Hope it helps.